# How to change style of each character of input text

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Here I want to randomly change the CSS of each character of text.
Like if I input *Stack*  I will get S in red, t in blue, a in green... etc on the bottom of the input field.

```js
var myModel = {
 name: "Mayur",
};

var myViewModel = new Vue({
 el: '#my_view',
 data: myModel
});
```

```css
span{
color:green;
font-weight:600;
font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="my_view">
  <label for="name">Enter name:</label>
  <input type="text" v-model="name" id="name" name="name" />
  <p>Welcome, <span>{{ name | uppercase }}</span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/deepaksingh/vjvMp/1403/ see if this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with Vue and I'm not familiar with its internal events and processes, but here's a tiny prototype i made in plain `JavaScript`:

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function (){
    let span = document.querySelector('span.letters'),
        text = span.textContent;
    span.innerHTML = '';
    Array.from(text).map(function(l){
        let color = document.createElement('span');
        color.innerHTML = l;
        color.style.color = 'rgb(' +
            randInterval(0, 255) + ',' +
            randInterval(0, 255) + ',' +
            randInterval(0, 255) + ')';
        span.appendChild(color);
    });
}

function randInterval(min,max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}
```

```html
<div><span class="letters">STACK</span></div>

<button>Random colors</button>
```

I've purposefully placed the function that randomizes each value of `rgb()` in a function, so you can alter it easily (now the colors are trully random). If you want to make the darker, you need to lower the `max` values. If you want the colors lighter, you need to increase the `min`s.

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<div>Type something here, then click on the white space beneave.</div>
<input type="hidden" id="hidden">
```

Javascript:

```
$("div").prop("contentEditable", true).blur(function(){
    var chars = $(this).text().split("");
    $("#hidden").val($(this).text());
    this.innerHTML = "";
    $.each(chars, function(){
        $("<span>").text(this).css({
            color: "#"+(Math.random()*16777215|0).toString(16)
        }).appendTo("div");
    });
});
```

Css:

```
div{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 400px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 2px 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

You can visit http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/Y8ySy/ for the implementation!

Both html and css codes are given in the link.
It gives the colour to the characters randomly but it can be manipulated easily or if you want them to run randomly, you can use it directly.