# Angular Material: Highlight Words in a Textbox

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular8

How do I Highlight Only the Text in Angular Material textbox,   and Not the whole inner box? I only want to highlight up from 's' to the end of 'i' in  (Sushi), not the whole box.

We will apply this to a read only textbox .
Also, reading Javascript manipulations are not ideal with Angular, so looking for appropriate way.

https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Favorite food" value="Sushi">
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <textarea matInput placeholder="Leave a comment"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: what did you mean to highlight only one character in every input?

Comment: I did not say that, please see question above

Comment: Can't do that within an input box... give this is a good workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43296121/8757883

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick solution is to highlight the text in the CSS for a certain class. This class can then be assigned for your readonly inputs. This solution isn't perfect but it might fit your needs

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22131214/how-to-highlight-text-inside-an-input-field) shows how to highlight only the text of an `input`, I suggest you read it to also see the limitations of this solution.

**CSS:**

```
.yourInputElement::first-line{
  background-color: gold; 
}
```

Here's a [simple example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fbfmsq) showing how it would work.

Hope that solves your issue :)