# Angular: NgStyle Highlight Words in a Textbox using input::first-line?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, ng-style, angular10

How do I highlight the contents of a textbox in Angular? the following is not working. Currently using Material textbox.

Need to apply it conditionally, based on boolean variable highlightTextFlag, maybe with ngstyle .

**Sample:**

```
input::first-line { 
   background-color: green !important; 
}
```

**Actual code:**

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Test</mat-label>   
    <input
        matInput 
        [ngStyle]="{'input::first-line': 'green' }"
    >
</mat-form-field>
```

[image]

[How to highlight text inside an input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22131214/how-to-highlight-text-inside-an-input-field)

[Angular Material: Highlight Words in a Textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59314682/angular-material-highlight-words-in-a-textbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the css in your component css file, but use a class name instead of the input selector as following:

```
.myInput::first-line{
//your css
}
```

And bind the class name to your Boolean variable in the component template as follows

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Test</mat-label>   
    <input
        matInput 
        [class.myInput]=“myBooleanVar”
    >
</mat-form-field>
```